# convergence of sequences in $T_4$ space

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

I have recently been asked this

For a normal Hausdorff space we are to show a sequence $x_n$ converges to $y$ iff for all continuous real-valued functions $f(x_n)$ converges to $f(y)$

One direction is easy enough but how to deduce convergence of sequence from convergence of functions?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Assume the sequence doesn't converge to $y$, construct a suitable function.

Comment: thats the thing i cant do that

Comment: and how to utilize normal space assumption?

Comment: If the sequence doesn't converge to $y$, what does that mean?

Comment: You are supposed to use the fact that $X$ is completely regular.

Comment: could you please show me the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Suppose that $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ does not converge to $y$. Then $y$ has an open nbhd $U$ such that $M=\{n\in\Bbb N:x_n\notin U\}$ is infinite; why? Now use the fact that your space is completely regular, by applying the definition of complete regularity to the point $y$ and the closed set $X\setminus U$, and show that the resulting function does what you want.